# Proving the distributive laws for ∩ and ∪

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would one prove the following distributive laws for the following:

1) A∪(B∩C)=(A∪B)∩(A∪C)

2) A∩(B∪C)=(A∩B)∪(A∩C)

We are given an example proof that the functions are associative:

```
A∪(B∪C)=A∪{x|x∈B∨x∈C}

        ={x|x∈A∨(x∈B∨x∈C)}

        ={x|(x∈A∨x∈B)∨x∈C}

        =(A∪B)∪C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the example you are given. I'm doing the first one, the other is similar.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
A \cup (B \cap C)&= A \cup \{x:x \in B \land  x \in C\} \\
&= \{ x : (x \in A) \lor (x \in B \land  x \in C) \} \\
&= \{ x : (x \in A \lor x \in B) \land (x \in A \lor x \in C) \} \\
&= (A \cup B)\cap(A \cup C). \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}